# Converting DOM Elements to HTML String

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser, rendering

I want to insert some content from the DOM elements into the .root tag. How can i do this?
Code;

```
setInterval(function() { 
    currentDOM = document.querySelector('.root').cloneNode(true);
    document.querySelector('.root').innerHTML = currentDOM; // it outputs [object HTMLDivElement]
}, 1);
```

Comment: Try `innerHTML = currentDOM.outerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
setInterval(function() { 
    currentDOM = document.querySelector('.root').cloneNode(true).innerHTML;
    document.querySelector('.root').innerHTML = currentDOM; // it outputs [object HTMLDivElement]
}, 1);
```